# Import module inside another module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a hard time trying to separate some utility code as a module.
I have the the following file structure:

```
scripts/
      |
      +-- toggle_keyboard.py
      PyUtils/
            |
            +-- sistema.py
            +-- strings.py
            +-- test_sistema.py
```

Sistema.py needs a class in strings.py, so it begins with:

```
from strings import String
```

And the Pytest test_sistema.py needs sistema.py, so it starts with:

```
import sistema as sis
```

Now, this is all fine when I run the tests with PyTest. However, I can't use this module in toggle_keyboard.py. I start it with:

```
import PyUtils.sistema as sis
```

And that gets me no compilation errors. However, when I run it, this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "toggle_keyboard.py", line 2, in <module>
    import PyUtils.sistema as sis
  File "/home/xxxxxx/scripts/PyUtils/sistema.py", line 2, in <module>
    from strings import String
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'strings'
```

Searching for similar problems online, I found that making use of "relative imports" could solve the problem. Indeed, I was able to run toggle_keyboard.py when I changed sistema.py with this:

```
from .strings import String
```

However, the test doesn't run anymore. When I execute PyTest now, I get:

```
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
PyUtils/test_sistema.py:1: in <module>
    import sistema as sis
PyUtils/sistema.py:2: in <module>
    from .strings import String
E   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

What would be a solution to make both the main script and the module's test to work?

Comment: do you have `__init__.py` files in those directories?  At the very least you should have one in PyUtils directory.

Comment: @alexpdev yes, I had already tried with a \_\_init\_\_.py file in PyUtils, as I saw mentioned in another question. Now I made an \_\_init\_\_.py for the root folder too (scripts/). It's making no difference, neither for running the test with relative import or for running the main program without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `sistema.py` file try:

```
from PyUtils.strings import String
```

and in `test_sistema.py`

```
import PyUtils.sistema as sis
```

and ensure your `PyUtils` directory contains an `__init__.py` file and that should fix the issue.

An alternative approach although one that is typically not recommended:
Add the top 3 lines from below in any file in the `scripts` dir that imports from the `PyUtils` dir.

`toggle_keyboard.py`

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path  
sys.path.insert(0, Path(__file__).parent / "PyUtils")   

from PyUtils.systema as sis
from PyUtils.strings import String
...
```

then the files in `PyUtils` can go back to:

```
from strings import String
import sistema as sis
```

You would still want to have the `__init__.py` in `PyUtils` dir.

And another approach would be to catch exceptions on the imports and try alternatives like so....

`sistema.py`

```
try:
    from strings import String
except ImportError:
    from PyUtils.strings import String
```

`test_sistema.py`

```
try:
   import sistema.py as sis
except ImportError:
   import PyUtils.sistema as sis
```

This is actually the better option in your situation.

Comment: That worked! But with a little inconvenience though: I can't open PyUtils as a standalone project (having the folder PyUtils as the root folder). If I do it, there's an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyUtils'". Is there a way of having PyUtils as a standalone project and importing it as a module from other projects without copying its folder inside as if it was part of these other projects?

Comment: @Leandro86 So your saying you want PyUtils to be the project root?  I don't undersand what you mean by standalone?  Are you not trying to set up a package? or are each of these files their own separate scripts?   If you plan to have your current working directory be PyUtils then you don't actually need the `__init__.py` but you will have to mess with the `sys.path`  in each of your files i think

Comment: What I meant was that I'd like to have PyUtils as an independent project in itself, with various utilities files and their own tests to be versioned in a git repository for them own. But at the same time, I'd like to be able to pull this project inside other projects to act as a module. And the problem is: the way I have to import dependencies (as in sistema.py importing strings.py) depends on the root path for the project being used at the time.

Comment: @Leandro86 Ok I got it.  Thanks for explaining.  See the additions I made to my answer for an alternative approach, and let me know if that causes any issues.

Comment: Thank you for both your solutions! I think I'll end up using the first one, since I may use the utility module more frequently than work on it. And when I have to work on it and run its tests, I'll temporally remove the project name from the internal imports. Thanks!

Comment: @Leandro86  your welcome .  your reply actually gave me another idea. Please see the last addition to the answer.

Comment: That was definitely the best approach! I didn't know you could have a try block in the imports. Now I don't have to change the imports when I switch the workspace. Thank you very much!